# rmarkdown - Increasing html width to fit entire table

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I was looking for a way to change the setting in my Rmd file so that the html output contains all the columns and the table does not break. I tried to change the css properties as in this solution ([Output table width in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323382/output-table-width-in-rmarkdown)) but this does not affect my output.

I have currently 17 columns and using a pandoc.table, but only 5 coloumns are shown before the table is broken and the next 5 columns are displayed below.

What changes do I need to make so that the entire table can be shown in my html output?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't use the `pandoc` package because is not currently available for R version 3.2.0. Instead, I used `knitr` with the `kable()` function. This code works fine:

```
{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
examp <- data.frame(matrix(rep("Unicorn"), nrow=5, ncol=100))
kable(examp)
```

I think, because you don't provide an example, that you need to specify the `results='asis'` chunk option.
Try ?kable for further information.

Anyway `?pandoc.table` shows that there is an option `split.table` that may help.