# My r markdown output page size is too small for the table

Tags: r, latex

Here is my type in the R

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]
Is there anyway to fix this??

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean "too small for tables" ?

Comment: @neilfws, yes, is there anyway to reduce the size of the table ?

Comment: You can include HTML within RMarkdown, so one way would be to wrap the table in HTML tags which specify font size. You can also increase page width, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323382/output-table-width-in-rmarkdown.

Comment: @neilfws I tried  insert the following into my rmarkdown,


<style type="text/css">

.table { "my table"

    width: 40%;

}
</style>  
.  There is nothing in my  output. I'm not sure how is this down, is there anything else that I'm missing ?

Comment: If your output is PDF, you'll have to investigate other solutions (perhaps involving LaTeX syntax). Google search for "rmarkdown page width" throws up lots of useful-looking suggestions, it seems like a common issue with solutions.